# convert axisX date to text in Html5 5 line chart

Tags: javascript, html

convert x-axis date to text in Html5  5 line chart, currently on x-axis 'jan,feb....' appearing . want to display text like subject name .Here is the refrence site is http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-line-chart/

```
 $(function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
          theme: "theme2",
          title:{
            text: "Line Chart"
          },
          animationEnabled: true,
          axisX: {
            valueFormatString: "MMM",
            interval:1,
            intervalType: "month"

          },
          axisY:{
            includeZero: false

          },
          data: [
          {        
            type: "line",
            //lineThickness: 3,        
            dataPoints: [
            { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414},
            { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520, indexLabel: "highest",markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle"},
            { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 460 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 450 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 480 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 480 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 410 , indexLabel: "lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross"},
            { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 500 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
            { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }

            ]
          }


          ]
        });

    chart.render();
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean this: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/labels-index-labels/ You can add a `label` item to your objects.

Comment: yes x-axis label but in case of line chart

Comment: http://icecream.me/a446209c18aa8b90a49c2266ad576d10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `label` key with value to the objects. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dkkC/85/).

```
dataPoints: [{
      x: new Date(2012, 00, 1),
      y: 450,
      label: '2012-00-01'
    }, {
      x: new Date(2012, 01, 1),
      y: 414,
      label: '2012-01-01'
    }, {
      x: new Date(2012, 02, 1),
      y: 520,
      label: '2012-02-01',
      indexLabel: "highest",
      markerColor: "red",
      markerType: "triangle"
    }, {
      x: new Date(2012, 08, 1),
      y: 410,
      label: '2012-08-01',
      indexLabel: "lowest",
      markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey",
      markerType: "cross"
    }, {
      x: new Date(2012, 09, 1),
      y: 500,
      label: '2012-09-01'
    },
```

Comment: thanks for response ,it worked ,i was not requiring month and date ,but by giving only label in place of x  solved my problem.